# error with ruby on heroku login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

i am a newbie in ruby, and I found a problem when trying to push my project on Heroku

when I execute:

```
    Heroku login
```

the result is:

```
rbconfig/datadir.rb and {Rb}Config.datadir is being deprecated from RubyGems.
It will be removed completely on or after June 2011. If you wish to rely on a
datadir, please use Gem.datadir.
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1245:in `<top (required)>': 
uninitialized constant RbConfig (NameError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I took 3 days looking for a solution to this problem, with no results

thanks for the help that you can give me

my OS is ubuntu 12.10

Comment: What version of Ruby/Rails/RubyGems are you using

Comment: the version is 1.8.24
 with (gem -v)

Comment: Please also run `ruby -v` as well as `rails --version` and tell us the results.

Comment: after you do a bundle update or bundle install does your rails app run or do you get errors

Comment: Also if you could give us a list of Gems installed on your machine we could help identify which Gem is causing the error

Comment: ruby -v: ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]
    ; rails --version: Rails 3.2.9, this is the result for bundle update and the list of Gems installed http://pastebin.com/tmG53fC7

Comment: ok, not sure if this related to your problem but you need to have sqlite3 being installed, Heroku uses Postgress so in your Gem File under your production group  you need to have gem 'pg' in it.

Comment: is true, but that I have it covered, the problem is I can not login in Heroku to even try to push

Comment: Have you upgraded to the Heroku Toolbelt, I know that Heroku no longer supports the gem version of Heroku

Comment: yes, i am using  heroku-toolbelt 2.34.0 (the last version)

Answer (score 1):

Find for a `'require "RbConfig/datadir"'` in  /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb file and delete it.

Thanks for the [source](https://github.com/taskjuggler/TaskJuggler/issues/3)

Comment: It doesn't appear that he has that particular gem installed.

Comment: "Removing 'require "RbConfig/datadir"' seems to do the trick"?? where I found that?

Comment: check this file /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb

Comment: doing that, and running heroku login, the result is: /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1245:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant RbConfig (NameError)
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
 from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Heroku Toolbelt? https://toolbelt.heroku.com/

The ruby gem is depreciated, don't use it

Comment: That would be my first step to fixing this - the gem is no longer updated. Install the toolbelt

Comment: i am using heroku-toolbelt 2.34.0 (the last version)